# Populating Word Table with Server Property

Tags: content-type, document-template

I am successfully using document property promotion and demotion in a current project.  There is a document library where the properties are used to fill out a templated Word document.  This is using Sharepoint 2010.

I have a requirement to take a single document property that stores a string that contains tabular data and the format really doesn't matter.  Then I have to fill out a word table using that document property.  Basically, we are using other properties to fill in simple labels (mailing, data, etc) but we want to use properties to fill out Word tables.

Any ideas?

Comment: so, you are adding values to a word template and are wanting them to be stored in SP? Not sure I understand your requirements fully. Can you give more info?
thanks,

Comment: Sure, I have a document library with custom properties that I have created.  There is a content type with a custom document template.  This document template has a word document.  The word document has fields that are populated using the custom properties from the document library.  This works beautifully.

I have a requirement now to generate a table using a custom property from the document library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create an event receiver looking for changes in the field and then applying the changes to the document using [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674469.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If the custom property that you want to put into a word table has (or could have) separators for each "table row", then you can write a simple word macro in vba to parse the custom property into your table.